# The script from <url> was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, npm, webpack

I have a Flask backend and my webpack configuration looks like this (with the sass/css/babel stripped out).

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('path').resolve;
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const config = {
    entry: {
        main: __dirname + '/js/index.jsx'
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    output:{
        path: resolve('../public'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.scss']
    },
     ...etc ...etc ...etc

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: './index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

When I execute a webpack-cli command `webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch`, `index.html` gets created correctly in `../public` as does `[name].[chunkhash].js`. example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app" />
        <script src="main.6e9f93766744ff757148.js?58e0a4a8c99dee0bfe93"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in Flask, I specify:

```py
app = Flask(__name__,
 template_folder="./templates/public")
```

So when you hit `localhost:<port>`, it should render `application/templates/public/index.html` (I do development in `application/templates/src`, then execute webpack command, that output is put into `application/templates/public`).

Now, when I fun `flask run`, the following output appears in the network:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2020 19:40:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2020 19:40:53] "GET /main.6e9f93766744ff757148.js?58e0a4a8c99dee0bfe93 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

and in developer tools, i can see the correct html and reference to the javascript in the response.

but the console states:

```
The script from <url>/<file>.js was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

So Flask is rendering the correct `html` file, but cannot find the javascript. How can I get Flask to find this javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Theres a package that can help with that - https://github.com/nickjj/flask-static-digest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was an issue with Flask, and not webpack or anything else. I had specified my static_folder to static/dist, when it should have just been set to static.